# Customize retries behaviour with Ribbon and Hystrix

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, netflix-ribbon

### Objective

I have a task to write API Gateway & load balancer with the following objectives:

- Gateway/LB should redirect requests to instances of 3rd party service (no code change = client-side service discovery)
- Each service instance is able to process only single response simultaneously, concurrent request = immediate error response.
- Services response latency is 0-5 seconds. I can't cache their responses, and therefore as I understand fallback is not an option for me. Also timeout is not an option, because latency is random and you haven't warranty you'll get better one on another instance.

### My solution

Spring Boot Cloud Netflix: Zuul-Hystrix-Ribbon. Two approaches:

1. *Retry*. Ribbon retry with fixed interval or exponential increase. I failed to make it work, the best result I achieved is `MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1000`, where Ribbon fires retries immediatelly and spamming donwstream services.
2. *Circuit Breaker*. Instead of adding exponential wait period in Ribbon, I can open circuit after few fails and redirect requests to another services. This also not the best approach for two reasons: a) having only few instances each with 0-5 sec latency means open all circuits very quickly and fail to serve request. b) my configuration doesn't work for some reason

### Question

How can I make Ribbon wait between retries? Or can I solve my problem with Circuit Breaker?

### My configuration

Full config could be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Volodymyr128/gateway/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml).

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: false
  # Obsolete option (Apache HttpClient by default), but without this Ribbon doesn't retry against another instances
  restclient:
    enabled: true

hystrix:
  command:
    my-service:
      circuitBreaker:
        sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 3000
        errorThresholdPercentage: 50
        requestVolumeThreshold: 5
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 5500

my-service:
  ribbon:
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: false
    NFLoadBalancerRuleClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.WeightedResponseTimeRule
    listOfServers: ${LIST_OF_SERVERS}
    ConnectTimeout: 500
    ReadTimeout: 4500
    MaxAutoRetries: 0
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1000
    retryableStatusCodes: 404,502,503,504
```

### Tests

In order to check your assumptions, you can play with [the test on GitHub](https://github.com/Volodymyr128/gateway/blob/master/src/test/java/com/vbakh/gateway/ApiGatewayHttpServerBasedIntegrationTest.java), that simulates single-thread service instances with different latencies